# UIView interpolation between 2 background images

Tags: swift, xcode

Let's say a UIView has a background image A, and I want to make an animation so A slowly turns into another image B.

how can I do this effect with images in background (png, for example)? I know that with just background colors, I can do this just by using UIView.animate

Comment: Use `UIView.animate` to animate the `alpha` of A from 100 -> 0, and the opposite for B.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [Core Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-SW239), particularly the 11 CICategoryTransition filter. Move your before/after CIImages into a CALayer, and animate.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two images in the same time (unless you haven't two imageView). That is the way with one `UIImageView`:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.imageView.alpha = 0.0

        }, completion: nil)


    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.imageView.alpha = 1.0
        self.imageView.image = self.secondImage

        }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `contents`property of `CALayer` is animatable, and you can assign CGImages to it. An animated change could look like this:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.animationDuration = 2.0;
theView.layer.contents = theNewImage.CGImage
CATransaction.commit();
```